# How to stop a long running function

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider this code:

```
class Solver {

   private boolean abort = false;

   public void solve(List<Case> cases) {
       while(!abort) {
           for(Case c : cases)
               compute(c); // method that take too long to finish
       }
   }

  // a bunch of methods

   public void abort() {
       abort = true;
   }
}

// in another class
Solver solver = new Solver();
solver.solve(cases);

public void onSolveAborted() {
    solver.abort();
}
```

How can I change this solution so I can abort the solve function instantly. I know I can implements the Runnable interface in Solver class so I can stop the thread. This will introduce many changes in our code and I don't know if the framework we are using allow creating threads.

Answer (score 1):

This will not be possible without the use of threads.  Something has to *set* `abort()` before the running thread will stop.  Take a look at this example:

```
class Solver implements Runnable {
    private List<Case> cases;

    public Solver(List<Case> cases) {
        this.cases = cases;
    }

    private void compute(Case c) {
        try {
            // Do some computation here
        } finally {
            // Sound the horns!  Abandon ship!
        }
    }

    public void solve(List<Object> cases) {
        for (Case c : cases) {
            try {
                compute(c); // method that take too long to finish
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Hmm, maybe I should take the hint...
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        solve(cases);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Case> cases = new ArrayList<Case>();

        // Populate cases

        Thread t = new Thread(new Solver(cases));

        t.run();

        do {
            // Wait 30 seconds
            t.join(30 * 1000);

            // Not done yet? Lets drop a hint..
            if(t.isAlive()) {
                t.interrupt();
            }
        } while (t.isAlive());
    }
}
```

Very simply, it launches solve in a thread.  The main thread waits up to 30 seconds then interrupts `solve` method.  The `solve` method catches the interruption and gracefully exits the computation.  Unlike your solution using `boolean abort`, this launches an `InterruptedException` from anywhere in your thead code (and you should deal with the exception accordingly!) allowing you to halt execution at any time.

If you want more control, you can add the `try.. catch` inside `compute` so you can have a `finally` clause to close any opened files or whatnot.  Perhaps better still, have a `try.. finally` in compute to deal with closing things in a "nice" way and the `try.. catch (InterruptedException)` in the `solve` method to handle what happens in the case of interruption (in short, cleanup logic and interruption logic don't have to be in the same method).

Answer (score 0):

Do somthing like this

Let say, you have 100 cases, 10 has been solved and you want to abort remaing 90.
In your code, you are solving all the cases in one iteration, after that while loop check for abort.

```
public void solve(List<Case> cases) {
    Iterator<Case> iterator = cases.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext() && !abort) {
        Case c=iterator.iterator.next();
        compute(c);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to Runnable and use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to run it. Then you can just use methods "shutDown()" or "shutDownNow()" methods. This is cleaner and less intrusive then what you suggested in your own question. Plus killing thread manually is a **REALLY BAD** idea. At some point in JDK itself in thread method "kill()" was killed as there is no clean way to do so properly

Comment: [shutdown()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) does nothing more than prevent new tasks from starting and leaving current threads running as they are and [shutdownNow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--) just calls interrupt on running tasks.  Nobody was suggesting to kill anything.

Comment: You are correct, but it is better to use shutdownNow() then deal with it in your own code, essentially inventing the wheel by writing your own ExecutionService

Comment: True.  I probably would have used ExecutionService if I wanted to run each case in parallel or anything minimally more complicated than the example above. Certainly not a bad idea to prefer it over Thread.  However the interruption logic in the thread code wouldn't change.